# is there any site i can type in a HTML color and see the actual color

Tags: html, colors

i would want to type in something like this:  #a6e2a6  and see the actual color

Comment: Come on guys, there are lots of questions not relevant to programming, but this is about a tool specifically useful to programmers (and designers). Thus, I don't support the 2 close requests I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several.  [ColorSpire](http://www.colorspire.com/), for example -- which also allows you to build up swatches into a site colour scheme.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com/). In my opinion; the coolest coler-app out there.

Answer (score 1):

[ColorPicker](http://www.colorpicker.com/) is nice for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://html-color-codes.info/ there is a colour picker below which you can use to paste your code and see the colour. It's green fyi.

By the way, it won't that you that long to write a simple HTML page right?

Simply write something like this and open it up in the browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css"><!--
      #colordisp{background: #a6e2a6; width:200px;height:200px;}
    --></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="colordisp"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was going to say something similar, but Steve's suggestion of ColorSpire convinced me: It's simpler, cooler and more versatile. When you're writing a program to bring about World Peace, you don't have time to write a HTML test page! ;)

Comment: Yep that's a cool site. Well about the html test page.... COPY IT FROM THIS ANSWER! =D

Answer (score 0):

see this [example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_bodybgstyle) at w3schools will help you